# How to remove "almost flat" trend lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

My code is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(pwt10)

p1 <- pwt10.0 %>% 
    mutate(my_color = ifelse(isocode == "KOR","Korea", "Other")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(year, labsh, group = isocode, color = my_color))+
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey", "white"))+
    xlim(1980,1997)

p1
```

And it turns out as:

[image]

I was wondering if there's a way to remove all "almost flat" grey lines and make the black line stand out (currently it is covered by other grey lines).

Answer (score 1):

The following code will put the blackline on top.

```
p1 <- pwt10.0 %>% 
    select(year, labsh, isocode) %>% 
    mutate(my_color = ifelse(isocode == "KOR", "Korea", "Other")) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, labsh, group = isocode, color = my_color)) +
    geom_line(data = . %>% filter(isocode != "KOR")) +
    geom_line(data = . %>% filter(isocode == "KOR")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey")) +
    labs(color = "Country") +
    xlim(1980,1997)

p1
```

As for the flat lines, they are *almost* flat, but only 3 are horizontal:

```
pwt10.0 %>%
    select(year, labsh, isocode) %>% 
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(isocode) %>%
    summarise(flat = diff(range(labsh)),
              flat = isTRUE(all.equal(flat, 0))) %>%
    filter(flat)
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  isocode flat 
#  <fct>   <lgl>
#1 LBN     TRUE 
#2 STP     TRUE 
#3 TGO     TRUE
```

---

Following a comment, the code below removes the flat lines.

```
p2 <- pwt10.0 %>% 
    select(year, labsh, isocode) %>% 
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(isocode) %>%
    mutate(slope = diff(range(labsh, na.rm = TRUE)),
           flat = isTRUE(all.equal(slope, 0))) %>%
    filter(!flat) %>%
    filter(abs(slope) >= 0.15) %>%
    select(-flat, -slope) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(my_color = ifelse(isocode == "KOR", "Korea", "Other")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, labsh, group = isocode, color = my_color)) +
    geom_line(data = . %>% filter(isocode != "KOR")) +
    geom_line(data = . %>% filter(isocode == "KOR")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey")) +
    labs(color = "Country") +
    xlim(1980,1997)

p2
```

Comment: So I am wondering how I can remove all those "almost flat" lines including the three perfectly horizontal one?

Comment: @joe Added code to remove the flat lines, see the edit. As for the almost flat ones, that would need a definition of almost flat.

Comment: thanks, for almost flat ones, is there anyway I can define the range of slope such as  `-0.05<slope <0.05`  using `isTRUE` function or other way around?

Comment: @joe Maybe `filter(abs(slope) >= 0.05)`.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried the code but all grey color lines turn into black. would you mind if you edit your original codes with `filter(abs(slope) >= 0.05)`?

Comment: @joe Done. It was a matter of putting `na.omit` nearer the beginning of the pipe. But some lines are still too flat, even with `filter(abs(slope) >= 0.10)`.